# jQuery .html method scrolls page to top

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's .html method as follows:

```
$(selector).html('some new html')
```

But whenever I do this, if the page is scrolled down it will auto-scroll to the top. Is there any way to stop this behaviour? Or an alternative to use that will not?

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this should happen. What does `selector` point to?

Comment: Does it replace so much content where the page becomes very short?

Comment: The only way this would happen is if the new content is much shorter in length than what was originally in the element

Comment: To be clear I am replacing the html in some cells in a row in a table. Only within one row

Answer (score 0):

False alarm it was not the .html() causing the behaviour but the fact that it was embedded in an  tag. My bad